# Spring FilterChainProxy with filterSecurityInterceptor not working correctly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring application with the config files as shown below. All configs seem correct but while debugging I found that, **during the initialization spring creates two beans for FilterSecurityInterceptor one without any intercept-url rules and the other with the rules that I have specified.** 
When a request comes, it uses the FilterSecurityInterceptor bean with no intercept-url rules. So I see the following log:

```
DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:183 - Public object - authentication not attempted
```

But the request URL falls under the intercept URL rule. I debugged and found that this is because the bean used didn't have any intercept rules in `httpMethodMap` of `DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource`.
I am not sure what is wrong here.

Below is the `applicationContext-security.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd"
    default-init-method="init">

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="userDetailService">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <alias name="filterChainProxy" alias="springSecurityFilterChain" />

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="consoleAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="custom_class">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/loginSuccess.htm" />
        <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="targetURL" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="consoleAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        class="custom_class">
        <property name="loginFailureUrl" value="/loginFailure.htm" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="consoleLogoutSuccessHandler"
        class="custom_class">
        <property name="logoutUrl" value="/loggedout.htm" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailService"
        class="custom_class">
    </bean>

    <security:http auto-config="true"
        security-context-repository-ref="securityContextRepository">
        <security:form-login authentication-failure-url="/loginFailure.htm"
            default-target-url="/loginSuccess.htm"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="consoleAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <security:logout success-handler-ref="consoleLogoutSuccessHandler" />
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:session-management
            session-fixation-protection="none" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/login.htm*"
                filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                filters="securityContextFilter, logoutFilter, formLoginFilter, servletApiFilter, exceptionTranslator, filterSecurityInterceptor" />
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityContextRepository"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />

    <bean id="securityContextFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <property name="securityContextRepository" ref="securityContextRepository" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="logoutFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="consoleLogoutSuccessHandler"
            index="0"
            type="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="servletApiFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter" />

    <bean id="exceptionTranslator"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
                <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="formLoginFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="consoleAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="consoleAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <security:filter-security-metadata-source>
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*"
                    access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
                    access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
        </property>
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `<security:http>` element in the config. From the documentation:

> **[38.1.2 <http>](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-http)**
>   Each `<http>` namespace block always creates an `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, an `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and a `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. These are fixed and cannot be replaced with alternatives.

So your `<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor">` is ignored. Instead of

```
<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <security:filter-security-metadata-source>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*"
                access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
                access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
    </property>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>
```

you should change `<security:http>` to include something like

```
<security:http ...
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    ...
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
</security:http>
```

You don't need `<bean id="accessDecisionManager">`, because (quote from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-http-attributes)) "by default an `AffirmativeBased` implementation is used for with a `RoleVoter` and an `AuthenticatedVoter`", which is exactly what you define.

Also your `<bean id="securityContextFilter">` is ignored, instead you should add `security-context-repository-ref="securityContextRepository"` attribute to `http` element.
And your `<bean id="exceptionTranslator">` is ignored, I'm not sure how to replace it properly.

And you manually define a lot of `org.springframework.security` beans. I suspect that most of them are either unnecessary (defined by default), or should be defined using specialized elements of `security:` namespace, instead of raw spring `bean`s.